# Using include or require within an ACF fieldgroup array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, include, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF for its flexible content block, and prefer to use the php as opposed to the UI. Thing is, I've got a lot of blocks, and the fieldgroup file is starting to get a little hard to manage.

I'd like to split out all my flexible content blocks into separate php files, and include them within the fieldgroup array, but I get a WP critical error.

The fieldgroup:

```php
<?php if(function_exists("acf_add_local_field_group"))
{
    acf_add_local_field_group(array (
        'key' => 'group_fieldgroup_fG98c698TJ5914z',
        'title' => 'Field Group',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_flexiblecontent_pE90n667AT9402l',
                'label' => 'Flexible Content Blocks',
                'name' => 'flexible_content_blocks',
                'type' => 'flexible_content',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array (
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ),
                
                'layouts' => array (
                    // here's what I'd like to do
                    require_once('content-block.php'),
                ),
                'button_label' => 'Add Block',
                'min' => '0',
                'max' => '0',
            ),
        ),
        
        // other options, location etc etc ...
        
    ));
} ?>
```

... and the file I'd like to include:

```php
<?php 'content_block_cN50e648YM9444c' => array (
    // Generic Field Settings
    'key' => 'content_block_cN50e648YM9444c',
    'label' => 'Content Block',
    'name' => 'content_block',
    'display' => 'block', // table / block / row
    
    'sub_fields' => array (
        // add subfields here
        array (
            // Generic Field Settings
            'key' => 'field_key',
            'label' => 'Field Label',
            'name' => 'field_name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => '',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 0,
            'wrapper' => array (
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            
            //Field Type Specific Settings
            'placeholder' => '',
            'prepend' => '',
            'append' => '',
            'maxlength' => '',
            'readonly' => 0,
            'disabled' => 0,
        ),
    ),
    'min' => '0',
    'max' => '1',
) ?>
```

This stripped down example results in the WP error.